# invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class var {
private:
    double value_;
    std::shared_ptr<var> left_;
    std::shared_ptr<var> right_;

public:
    var(const double& v) : value_(v){};

    friend var operator+(const var& l, const var& r) {
        var result(l.value_ + r.value_);
        left_ = std::make_shared<var>(l.value_);
        right_ = std::make_shared<var>(r.value_);
        return result;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const var& var) {
        os << var.value_;
        return os;
    }
};

int main() { var a(1); }
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘var operator+(const var&, const var&)’:
test.cpp:17:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘var::r_’
   17 |         r_.push_back(std::make_shared<var>(l.value_));
      |         ^~
test.cpp:10:39: note: declared here
   10 |     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<var>> r_;
      |                                       ^~
```

I am struggling to understand why I am getting the error in the title.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you include the *full* error message in your question?

Comment: `left_ = ...` and `right_ = ...` should be `result.left_ = ...` and `result.right_ = ...`. You just forgot to name the instance whose members you want to assign. The error message should be pretty clear. `left_` and `right_` are members, and they aren't static so you need to access them via an instance.

Comment: The error message and the code doesn't match. Please make sure that you create a proper [mre] to show us, and then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log from that exact example.

Comment: There is no variable called `r_` or any invocation of `push_back` in the code you have posted. Therefore any attempt at answering your question is speculation.

Comment: The usual approach to this sort of problem is to define `operator+=` as a member, which modifies the object that it's applied to. Then implement `operator+` by creating a result object with a copy of one of the values, and adding the other value to it with `+=`. Voila: no `friend` declarations!

Comment: @PeteBecker I think using a `friend` for `operator+` is quite common as well. Do you see any problem with this approach in principle ?

Comment: @wohlstad -- if you do that, how would you implement `+=` efficiently?

Comment: @PeteBecker I understand your point about efficient implementation for `+=`. I guess so far I encounter classes where adding 2 instances has no efficiency issue.

Comment: Having now actually looked at what the `operator+` does, it doesn't seem that `+=` makes sense. I provided generic advice for arithmetic types; this isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `friend var operator+` is not a member of the class.
In order to access data members it should **specify the instance**.

Therefore change:

```
  left_ = std::make_shared<var>(l.value_);
  right_ = std::make_shared<var>(r.value_);
```

To:

```
//vvvvvvv---------------------------------------
  result.left_ = std::make_shared<var>(l.value_);
  result.right_ = std::make_shared<var>(r.value_);
```

---

Note:
As commented above by @PeteBecker: in the general arithmetic case a more efficient approach would be to implement `operator+=` as a member, and then implement `operator+` in terms of it (create a copy of the 1st argument, use `operator+` to add the 2nd to it and return it).
It is probably not relevant in this specific case, since `operator+=` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: damn it. such a rookie error. I have been away from c++  for too long.

Comment: @HMPtwo -- the usual practice is to wait a day or so before accepting an answer; you might get a better one.